# Windows active directory authentication for website built in angular Js and jsp servlet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, ldap

We have our intranet website built in mostly javascript, angular js and bit of jsp servlet.
The current authentication process is by using username password and validating it with entries in database which is oracle 11g. The entire infrastructure is hosted on oracle linux 6.
We are in process of moving to windows active directory authentication for our intranet website.
Can you guys please point me to some open source solution for this. And also please point to documentation on implementing it.

Thanks